# Adding Tokens to an Array C

Tags: c, arrays, null, token, strtok

So I'm trying to add tokens to an array the if statement keeps verifying that the array, tokenHolder, is empty. My second while loop is where I try to input tokens into the array. However no tokens are inputted into the array and I don't understand why.

```
char* token;
int* bufflength = 0;
char* buffer = NULL;
char input[25000];
char *tokenHolder[2500];
int pos = 0;

while(1){

     printf("repl> ");
     getline(&buffer, &bufflength, stdin);
     token = strtok(buffer, "");

     //code to input tokens into array
     while(token != NULL){
         pos++;
         token = strtok(NULL, "");
         tokenHolder[pos] = token;
        }

         if(tokenHolder[0] == NULL){
             printf("It's NULL");
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You increment `pos` to `1` before you save any token, so nothing is ever assigned to `tokenHolder[0]`.

Either use (note the use of blank rather than an empty string as the delimiter):

```
tokenHolder[0] = token = strtok(buffer, " ");
```

(or an equivalent) or do something like:

```
char *data = buffer;
while ((tokenHolder[pos++] = strtok(data, " ")) != NULL)
    data = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char *tokenHolder[2500] = { NULL };
...
while(token != NULL){
    tokenHolder[pos++] = token;
    token = strtok(NULL, "");
}

if(tokenHolder[0] == NULL){//or if(pos == 0){
    printf("It's NULL");
}
```